# OAuth non-interactive login

Tags: authentication, oauth, non-interactive

I'm building a console application that needs to access information from REST API secured with OAuth. Is it possible to run it in background i.e. w/o requiring browser redirection for authentication. The only option I see right now is to mimic browser but this seems too messy.

Comment: I have the same question now.  I'm using ClientLogin for a GUI app and it's starting to return `401 Not Authorized` for certain accounts.  I know that OAuth is now recommended over ClientLogin, but this is an automated application for a single client, and a manual login is highly undesirable.